# Problems knitting in R markdown: object not found

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm having an issue where my code runs fine, but won't knit in R markdown. I think somehow I haven't properly specified the object though I use all the libraries, import the dataset and include all my transformations. Here is the error:

`Quitting from lines 292-502 (PICH-Selected-Hisotgrams.Rmd)  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'logTGFA' not found Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> f -> scales_add_defaults -> lapply -> FUN Execution halted`

The code is:

```
`data=TwentyPrecentdata1
ggplot(data, aes(x=logTGFA, fill= PICH.factor, color=PICH.factor)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +
  labs(title="TGFA histogram plot",x="log TGFA (pg/mL)", y = "Count") +
  scale_color_manual(values=lacroix_palette("Mango", type = "discrete")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=lacroix_palette("Mango", type = "discrete"))`
```

The object I want to call, which is present in the dataset "TwentyPercentdata1"
is "TwentyPercentdata1$logTGFA"

Any help appreciated. I can share more of the code as needed.

Comment: You maybe have a typo? Your code show `Precent`, but your text shows `Percent` in the name of the data frame - with the `e` and the `r` switched. Since `data=TwentyPrecentdata1` didn't seem to throw an error, perhaps that issue occurs earlier in your document as well?

Comment: Well how embarrassing--thank you for your sharp eyes @GregorThomas ! I will fix this now

Comment: Did Gregor's hint solve your issue?

Comment: Gregor saved the day! My document knits now!